# How to lock on to a particular skeleton in Kinect SDK 2.0?

Tags: c#, kinect

Previously working with Kinect SDK 1.8 we had methods to lock to a particular skeleton to avoid other people in sensor view from interfering in application functionalities.

```
CurrentSkeletonId = skeleton.TrackingId;
                           this.kinect.SkeletonStream.AppChoosesSkeletons = true;
                           this.kinect.SkeletonStream.ChooseSkeletons(this.CurrentSkeletonId);
```

I dont see similar methods in Kinect SDK 2.0. Isnt this available in SDK 2.0? If not how can I achieve this functionality?